# Suggesting compatability level based on min and max value

Tags: python, django

I am stuck with a somehow reasonable request from a client but harder to implement (and downvotes for sure :p). The application includes State, City, County etc. Each one has weather related information for a range of month. A typical model is now:

```
class County(models.Model):
    min_temp=models.DecimalField()
    max_temp=models.DecimalField()

class Person(models.Model):
    prefer_min_temp=models.DecimalField()
    prefer_max_temp=models.DecimalField()
```

So basically, when a person choses a county, we want to tell him his comptabiity based on the min and max temperature he has declared he prefers on a scale of  0-30 (Weak),31-50 (Good), 51-70 (Fair), >71 (Excellent)

E.g.

```
prefere_min_temp=50, max=90
```

County:

```
min_temp=30, max_temp=100
```

How do I go about handling this for temperatures that can vary significantly with low percentage of error, since it is an a recommendation?

Comment: What kind of output do you want here? Just a boolean? Or a sliding scale? Can you give an example of exactly what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Are you sure maximum and minimum temperatures is the most useful measure of a county's climate? It might be more useful to use mean temperature and standard deviation instead. Also there's variation between seasons, which can vary a lot between locations.

Comment: @HåkenLid: it is the client's choice, not mine. Also, the model has more detail such as month ranges (Jan-March etc). But since it is early stage, I can definitely recommend something better including mean temperature if it yields more accurate compatibility suggestion.

Comment: The output should be simple a simple value: Weak, Good, Fair or Excellent (a numberical representation would be nice but not strictly needed)

Comment: I would write a [quantile function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_function) to calculate the probability that the county's temperature will fall inside the preferred max and min. The output would be between 0 and 1. Pass that to another function that maps from a number to a discrete category in the range Weak-Excellent. It's probably reasonable to assume that the temperature range in a single month is close to a normal distribution